# Is possible to use sbt-release plugin with Subversion as SCM?

Tags: scala, svn, release, sbt

I'm evaluating the usage of Play 2 framework to hotsites at the company I've worked for. However, I've seen that the [sbt-release plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) doesn't work with SVN, and the documentation seems to suggest not using it.

Is there anyone who tried this approach successfully?

Comment: It doesn't have built-in support for SVN, but it is flexible.  For example, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#customizing-the-release-process.  What about it suggests not using it, though?

Comment: Your comment is pertinent, @mark-harrah. I would indeed suggest to migrate for git, instead of forcing using svn. Thanks for it!